# Playback of segmented hls stream with m3u8 playlist

Tags: mediaelement.js, http-live-streaming

Can mediaelement player play a segmented mpegts hls stream defined in an m3u8 playlist and if so could you show the code to do this. In my case there is a test.m3u8 playlist on a webserver:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:7291
#EXTINF:12,
test-7291.ts
#EXTINF:12,
test-7292.ts
#EXTINF:12,
test-7293.ts
#EXTINF:12,
test-7294.ts
#EXTINF:12,
test-7295.ts
#EXTINF:12,
test-7296.ts
#EXTINF:12,
test-7297.ts
#EXTINF:12,
test-7298.ts
#EXTINF:12,
test-7299.ts
#EXTINF:12,
test-7300.ts
```

iOS devices can view the live stream with no problems.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can.
Put src to .m3u8 in your video tag:
`<video src="/link/to/your_file.m3u8" />`

and init plugin:

`var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];`

`var player = new MediaElement(video);`

Player would start to play from first item in .m3u8 list.
Moreover the ability to play m3u8 lists is not mediaelement.js merit, it's platform feature

Answer (score 1):

You need to make some changes in the library. You can check out my changes. By just adding m3u8 in the supported formats it seems to work perfectly.
https://github.com/sourcebits-harshitakasera/mediaelement-and-player-v2
It seems to work for me.