# mediaelement.js support of HLS

Tags: mediaelement.js, http-live-streaming

Does mediaelement.js support HLS?  I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002344/playback-of-segmented-hls-stream-with-m3u8-playlist) very simple example, which claims HLS support.  I also found [this](http://www.projekktor.com/board/index.php?mode=thread&id=1840) thread also claiming HLS support stating the importance of the mime.  However, I could not get any of my streams or any samples I could find on the web to play.  Are there any browser, OS, or mime requirements to get this to work?

Answer (score 3):

You need to make some changes in the library. You can check out my changes. By just adding m3u8 in the supported formats it seems to work perfectly. https://github.com/sourcebits-harshitakasera/mediaelement-and-player-v2 It seems to work for me.